# how to get parameter from URL of byte[] to servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Need your help

I'm sending confirmation link to mail Id to get activated ,sending username in url so, i have encrypted the String username to byte[]

```
http://localhost:8080/link_expiry/Acct_pen?uname=[B@11d42b72&pt=1488436457838
```

As you notice ,my username in url got encrypted and the question is ????

How can i get this username of byte[] to servlet to validate the user..

```
 KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
             SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
             Cipher desCipher;
             desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");

        /*  **String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
            System.out.println("username from link" +uname); */**

            byte[] ci=uname.getBytes();
            System.out.println("byte[] ci"+ci);
            desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
             byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(ci);
             System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + new String(textDecrypted));
```

If it is a string we can get as request.getParameter("uname");

Can you please help me out..????????

encrypting string

```
KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
        Cipher desCipher;
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");

       desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
       byte[] text =uname.getBytes();
       byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
       System.out.println("username Encryted : " + textEncrypted);
```

o/P:-
[B@11d42b72

How to get this to servlet which is in byte[]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'll get it as a string with getParameter method. If you want it as an array you can use `String.toCharArray()`

```
String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
char[] unameArr = uname.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Had this error????????????       javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:750)

Comment: maybe your encrypted string is wrong? As you can see the input must be a multiple of 8.